# Highlighting lines in eclipse, like with a textmarker

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In Eclipse Helios I want to highlight selected lines using a custom background color, like one would do with a text marker for normal text on paper.

How can I do that? Is there a (stable) Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, there is. Atleast as a workaround.

Mark a line as a bookmark; Right click on the line number field in the java editor, choose "Add bookmark"
The go to preferences; General - Editors - Text Editors - Annotations.
Choose bookmarks in the table, select "Text as highlighted"

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: First step in the right direction, but I need different colors and the annotation stuff looks a bit uncomfortable (like setting breakpoints *shrugg*)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make your own marker type and dictate what the text annotation should look like, read through http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html .  If you're looking to do this with your own file type, you'll have to go into more detail--and pick a file type that can support remembering such things itself.

Comment: Looks more like an overkill to my problem. I simply want to hightlight some java source code and change the background color of the text. This way I could e.g. mark different code paths for debugging.