# eclipse single line color

Tags: eclipse

how can I change the color of a single line in Eclipse to be able to find it fast while scrolling ? many people are suggesting to download eclipse themes but I am interested in changing the color of a single line to be able to re-find it faster

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925193/highlighting-lines-in-eclipse-like-with-a-textmarker It's definitely a workaround but if you can find a keyboard shortcut for setting and removing bookmarks it might just do the trick

Answer (score 2):

You can leave this little comment in that line:

```
// TODO
```

A small blue rectangle will be shown next to the scrollbar (the same way as your errors and warnings), and you will be able to instanlty find that line by clicking on it.

Comment: yea the blue ectangle will do for now until I learn how to make a plug-in for eclipse. thanks.