# Eclipse - Mark line for later editing

Tags: eclipse, ide, tags, eclipse-juno, eclipse-kepler

is there a possibility in eclipse to mark multiple lines in different classes of a project for later editing, so i can write some test code and afterwards before i release my software i got the possibility to show all the marked lines and delete or edit them ?

I know the Tasks in eclipse just not sure if this is the right way to go, because i have to enter the name of the Task everytime and there isn't the possibility to group them together as far as i know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use a comment //TODO. Either will show up in the Tasks view and will give you special markers on the right bar (like you'll see for warnings or errors. //FIXME will work, too.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the @TODO annotated javadoc tag.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/taglet/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Just for other folks that will see this question, you can mark a line as a boolmark, see this answer: [Highlighting lines in eclipse, like with a textmarker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925193/highlighting-lines-in-eclipse-like-with-a-textmarker)