# Eclipse, mark lines with highlight

Tags: eclipse

Is there anyway we can **highlight** multiple lines and **keep them highlighted**, for future reference or just to easily mark different parts of the code.

I saw this thread [Highlighting lines in eclipse, like with a textmarker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925193/highlighting-lines-in-eclipse-like-with-a-textmarker), it actually  is a smart workaround, but the downside is I **can't select multiple bookmarks at once**.

Is there a better way of doing this? thanks !