# How to highlight selected world in Eclipse Javascript Oxygen?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Notepad++, Sublimetext and almost all this kind of editors highlight a word (f.i. a variable) when you select that word with the mouse.
How can I acomplish this thing with Eclipse? Is it possible?

[image]

An example of Javascript code (test.js file) in my Eclipse Javascript project:

[image]

Eclipse version:

- Eclipse for JavaScript and Web Developers
- Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
- Build id: 20180405-1200

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925193/highlighting-lines-in-eclipse-like-with-a-textmarker

Comment: It depends on the editor: e. g. the _Generic Text Editor_ supports it, the normal _Text Editor_ not and the Java editor distinguishes between variables in different scopes.

Comment: Sorry, I mean javascript. I prefer Eclsipse ignores the scope to highlight something

Comment: It depends on the editor you use for the JavaScript code (there are more than one JavaScript/HTML/... editors for that), e. g. see https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/using_javascript_mark_occurences.htm

Comment: "Mark occurrences" is selected and in Preferences > Javascript > Editor > Mark Occurrences is all checked... but it doesn't work

Comment: Which Eclipse version and package do you use? Do you have any plugins installed for JavaScript? Is it a `.js`, `.html` or `.php` file? Can you give a code example?

Comment: I have added more information about Eclipse version and an example